# ¿Cómo mostrar registros del mes anterior en el caso que el mes seleccionado sea Enero dentro de un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un procedimiento almacenado en dónde debo mandar como parámetros una línea (parte de una columna de mi tabla), el mes actual y el año actual. Al mandar estos parámetros debo mostrar una información de mi tabla.

Muestro lo que he trabajado hasta ahora:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
@NIVEL VARCHAR(15),
@MES INT,
@AÑO INT
)
AS
BEGIN

IF @NIVEL = 'LINEA MC'
    BEGIN
        (SELECT LINEAMC, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS DEBITO, SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS CREDITO, SUM(MONTODEBITO) - SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS TOTAL
         FROM PRUEBAOPEX
         WHERE MONTH(FECHA) = @MES
         AND YEAR(FECHA) = @AÑO
         GROUP BY LINEAMC)
         UNION ALL
         (SELECT LINEAMC, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS DEBITO, SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS CREDITO, SUM(MONTODEBITO) - SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS TOTAL
          FROM PRUEBAOPEX
          WHERE MONTH(FECHA) = @MES - 1
          AND YEAR(FECHA) = AÑO
          GROUP BY LINEAMC)
    END
ELSE
    RAISERROR('Línea Incorrecta', 16, 1)
END
```

En el caso que seleccione un número diferente a uno (representa Enero) me muestra los registros correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera fila representa los registros en febrero, la segunda los registros en enero.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo tendría que hacer en el caso de indicar el mes de enero, para se me filtre el mes de enero (me los muestra) y los registros del mes de diciembre del año anterior sin desprenderme del parámetro @Año en dónde selecciono el año?

De antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en tu tabla tienes una columna de fecha, lo mejor es convertir tus parámetros a fechas para manejarlos mejor y puedes optimizar la consulta al permitir el uso de índices y evitar leer la tabla múltiples veces.

Usando la función `DATEFROMPARTS`, podemos transformar el año y mes en la fecha del primer día de cada mes. Con eso, solo necesitamos sumar o restar meses usando la función `DATEADD`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
    @NIVEL VARCHAR(15),
    @MES INT,
    @AÑO INT
)
AS
IF @NIVEL = 'LINEA MC'
BEGIN
    SELECT  LINEAMC, 
            (YEAR(FECHA) * 100) + MONTH( FECHA) AS PERIODO,
            SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS DEBITO, 
            SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS CREDITO, 
            SUM(MONTODEBITO) - SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS TOTAL
        FROM PRUEBAOPEX
        WHERE FECHA >= DATEADD( MM, -1, DATEFROMPARTS( @AÑO, @MES, 1)
        AND   FECHA <  DATEADD( MM,  1, DATEFROMPARTS( @AÑO, @MES, 1)
        GROUP BY LINEAMC, ( YEAR(FECHA) * 100) + MONTH( FECHA);
END
ELSE
    RAISERROR('Línea Incorrecta', 16, 1);
```